# Why didn't the compass take me to where I last slept?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have fun playing under my world and tried to run under my house but accidentally ran the wrong way and got lost.

I used a compass which I read will help me find my bed. The last place I slept was in the middle of nowhere yet it still took me back to my house.

Why did it take me back to my house and not to where I last slept?

Comment: Please don't use random tags and do please try to put some effort into formatting and flow.

Answer (score 9):

The compass points towards the *World Spawn Point*. This is the point where you first spawned on this map.

This point will not change based on where you've set your individual spawn point.

The only way to change it is by using the `/setworldspawn` command.